# Flutter Backdrop Animation

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm working a little bit with Flutter and I understand everything except Animations (i never liked working with animations).

I've tried to implement a [Backdrop](https://material.io/design/components/backdrop.html) in my Flutter app using this Flutter [Demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/backdrop_demo.dart). Implementing the Backdrop is easy.

I stuck on implementing the navigation of the Backdrop which let it slide down and up by the hamburger button.
I have read the [Animations in Flutter](https://flutter.io/tutorials/animation/) Tutorial. I understood the basics of animations (controller, animation etc.). But in this Backdrop example, it is a little bit different.

Can someone explain to me this case step by step? Thanks.

Comment: I am maintainer of [backdrop](https://pub.dev/packages/backdrop) package on pub.dev - we have implemented navigation with backdrop in it. Please check the examples and code to get better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to reach a solution combining the information of the following links. Please note that I’m not an expert in Flutter (neither animations). That being said, suggestions and corrections are really appreciated.

- Backdrop implementation:
  https://github.com/material-components/material-components-flutter-codelabs/blob/104-complete/mdc_100_series/lib/backdrop.dart
- Animation:
  https://medium.com/@vigneshprakash15/flutter-image-rotate-animation-6b6eaed7fb33

After creating your backdrop.dart file, go to the **_BackdropTitle** class and edit the part where you define the **IconButton** for the menu and close icons. You have to perform a rotation in the **Opacity** item that contains the Icon:

```
icon: Stack(children: <Widget>[
  new Opacity(
    opacity: new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: new ReverseAnimation(animation),
      curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0),
    ).value,
    child: new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      child: new Container(
        child: new Icon(Icons.close),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
        return new Transform.rotate(
          angle: animationController.value * -6.3,
          child: _widget,
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  new Opacity(
    opacity: new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animation,
      curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0),
    ).value,
    child: new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      child: new Container(
        child: new Icon(Icons.menu),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
        return new Transform.rotate(
          angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
          child: _widget,
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
],
```

I had to use a negative value in the angle of the close transformation in order to rotate it in the same direction of the menu animation.

And here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'menu.dart';

const double _kFlingVelocity = 2.0;

class Backdrop extends StatefulWidget {
  final MenuCategory currentCategory;
  final Widget frontLayer;
  final Widget backLayer;
  final Widget frontTitle;
  final Widget backTitle;

  const Backdrop({
    @required this.currentCategory,
    @required this.frontLayer,
    @required this.backLayer,
    @required this.frontTitle,
    @required this.backTitle,
  })  : assert(currentCategory != null),
    assert(frontLayer != null),
    assert(backLayer != null),
    assert(frontTitle != null),
    assert(backTitle != null);

  @override
  _BackdropState createState() => _BackdropState();
}

class _BackdropState extends State<Backdrop>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey _backdropKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'Backdrop');

  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    value: 1.0,
    vsync: this,
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
void didUpdateWidget(Backdrop old) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(old);

  if (widget.currentCategory != old.currentCategory) {
    _toggleBackdropLayerVisibility();
  } else if (!_frontLayerVisible) {
    _controller.fling(velocity: _kFlingVelocity);
  }
}

Widget _buildStack(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
  const double layerTitleHeight = 48.0;
  final Size layerSize = constraints.biggest;
  final double layerTop = layerSize.height - layerTitleHeight;

  Animation<RelativeRect> layerAnimation = RelativeRectTween(
    begin: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        0.0, layerTop, 0.0, layerTop - layerSize.height),
    end: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  ).animate(_controller.view);

  return Stack(
    key: _backdropKey,
    children: <Widget>[
      widget.backLayer,
      PositionedTransition(
        rect: layerAnimation,
        child: _FrontLayer(
          onTap: _toggleBackdropLayerVisibility,
          child: widget.frontLayer,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var appBar = AppBar(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    elevation: 0.0,
    titleSpacing: 0.0,
    title: _BackdropTitle(
      animationController: _controller,
      onPress: _toggleBackdropLayerVisibility,
      frontTitle: widget.frontTitle,
      backTitle: widget.backTitle,
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          // TODO
        },
      )
    ],
  );
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: appBar,
    body: LayoutBuilder(builder: _buildStack)
  );
}

bool get _frontLayerVisible {
  final AnimationStatus status = _controller.status;
  return status == AnimationStatus.completed ||
      status == AnimationStatus.forward;
}

void _toggleBackdropLayerVisibility() {
  _controller.fling(
      velocity: _frontLayerVisible ? -_kFlingVelocity : _kFlingVelocity);
  }
}

class _FrontLayer extends StatelessWidget {
  const _FrontLayer({
    Key key,
    this.onTap,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 16.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTap: onTap,
            child: Container(
              height: 40.0,
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: child,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BackdropTitle extends AnimatedWidget {
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final Function onPress;
  final Widget frontTitle;
  final Widget backTitle;

  _BackdropTitle({
    Key key,
    this.onPress,
    @required this.frontTitle,
    @required this.backTitle,
    @required this.animationController,
  })  : assert(frontTitle != null),
    assert(backTitle != null),
    assert(animationController != null),
    super(key: key, listenable: animationController.view);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation = this.listenable;

    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.title,
      softWrap: false,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
        // branded icon
        SizedBox(
          width: 72.0,
          child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
            onPressed: this.onPress,
            icon: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              new Opacity(
                opacity: new CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: new ReverseAnimation(animation),
                  curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0),
                ).value,
                child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: animationController,
                  child: new Container(
                    child: new Icon(Icons.close),
                  ),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
                    return new Transform.rotate(
                      angle: animationController.value * -6.3,
                      child: _widget,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              new Opacity(
                opacity: new CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: animation,
                  curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0),
                ).value,
                child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: animationController,
                  child: new Container(
                    child: new Icon(Icons.menu),
                  ),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
                    return new Transform.rotate(
                      angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
                      child: _widget,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
        // Here, we do a custom cross fade between backTitle and frontTitle.
        // This makes a smooth animation between the two texts.
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Opacity(
              opacity: CurvedAnimation(
                parent: ReverseAnimation(animation),
                curve: Interval(0.5, 1.0),
              ).value,
              child: FractionalTranslation(
                translation: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: Offset.zero,
                  end: Offset(0.5, 0.0),
                ).evaluate(animation),
                child: backTitle,
              ),
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: CurvedAnimation(
                parent: animation,
                curve: Interval(0.5, 1.0),
              ).value,
              child: FractionalTranslation(
                translation: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: Offset(-0.25, 0.0),
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).evaluate(animation),
                child: frontTitle,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find a sample demo for backdrop in flutter gallery..which you will get while installing Flutter.